# uTorrent remote asks to touch screen and move to login without success

Tags: iphone, safari, login

When I browse from my iphone 4 it takes me `remote.utorrent.com/srp`

The it asks me to

> Touch screen and Move
>
> Touch the screen and move your finger to fill the progress bar below...

[image]

This worked both on my PC and MacBook, but now does not work on the iPhone.

- Can anyone reproduce?
- What could the problem be?
- Is there any way around this?

I have iOS 5.0

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the question was ready I solved the problem.

I was on inPrivate mode and for whatever reason, it does not detect the moving.

As soon as you go to the normal browsing mode, it detects correctly the movement.

If anyone can figure out **why** that happens, it would be great to know.

Anyway, I hope this can help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have specific details, but certain events and media types are disabled when browsing in Private Mode. A notable one is any sort of audio/video media.

If you enable private mode you can't view embedded video or audio. For example, enable private mode and visit YouTube or Vimeo, you will get a play icon with a cross through it. Same goes for any sites that embed MP3s or other media into a page, these will not work. It seems that there are certain events included in this list; location tracking will not be allowed, and while I don't know exactly what uTorrent employs on that page, it's obvious that it doesn't work for the same reason as the above either.

I can't find any documentation on the matter on Apple nor anyone else's site, nor info on why this change was made. I have to believe it was intentional, but I don't how playing media will eventually result in leaking private data even with Private Mode on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep Safari in private mode, you can download Chrome for iPhone. That happened to me too and using Chrome is all OK..